# How to stream tweets from specific accounts

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm using the twitter npm package in an attempt to stream tweets from specified accounts.

I'm having trouble navigating the twitter api docs, so I'm a little confused.

I can hit the REST endpoint to get the specified user tweets info with:

```
    var client = new Twitter({});

    client.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name: user }, function(error, tweets) {
      if(error) throw error;
      console.log(tweets);
    });
```

How do I stream the tweets? Is it even possible? If not, how else could I accomplish this? I would like this to be as responsive and immediate as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
    var stream = client.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: userId });

    stream.on('data', function(event) {
      console.log(event && event.text);
    });
```

This will client stream reader will display the tweets as they are made automatically.

Unfortunately, the screen_name of the user cannot be used, so you'll have to find that out beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code below and was able to get last 20 tweets of a user and save them in a file `log.txt`.

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var fs = require("fs");

//Your keys go inside {}
var client = new Twitter({});

//These are the parameters for the API call
var params = {
    screen_name: 'damiengold', //use damiengold instead of @damiengold
    count: 20
};

//Perform the API call and return data
client.get('statuses/user_timeline.json', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
    var dataToFile;
    if (!error) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
            console.log(tweets[i].created_at + " " + tweets[i].text);
            console.log("-------------------------------");

            dataToFile = tweets[i].created_at + " " + tweets[i].text + "\n-----------\n";

            //This block of code will append tweets to the file called "log.txt".
            fs.appendFile("log.txt", dataToFile, function(err) {

                // If the code experiences any errors it will log the error to the console.
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
            })
        }
    }

    console.log("Last 20 tweets are now displayed on the screen and saved in log.txt.");

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was looking for a real-time solution that wouldn't require me to run this in a setInterval

Comment: What do you mean by setInterval?

Comment: @Robodude I haven't faced any issues getting the data in real time.

Comment: If you check out my solution, you'll see more of what I was trying to do. It automatically gets the tweets via the stream so the rest api call doesn't need to be manually invoked.